# Unable to get current location Longitude and Latitude using GPS

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I am try to use my GPS to get the Longitude and Latitude of my current location. But i am getting nothing, I am also not getting any type of errors or logcat. Here is my code that I am using

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
protected LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.e("--", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
    Log.e("--", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.e("--", String.valueOf(status));

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.e("--", String.valueOf(provider));
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.e("--", String.valueOf(provider));
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes GPS is enabled

Comment: Have you put <uses-permission/> in the manifest?

Comment: Also u have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in manifest ?

Comment: both <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: You using Log.e, also using  Error filter in logcat too ?

Comment: yes  I am using that filter

Comment: Is this code working on your device..???

Comment: I directly copy and paste your code. And it's working

Comment: It's not even working in my emulator

Comment: Were you trying all thing on emulator ?

Comment: nope I am trying on my phone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110082/discussion-between-blackkara-and-shivam).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I drop my idea of using specific provider as on one of my phone's GPS is not working fine. I used Criteria to let the system choose it for me if it is best else it will choose another one. so when my GPS is no working properly(works fine on one phone and not on other) it choose network location provide.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)             context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0,0, this);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(location != null )
    {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
```

hopes this helps